# Why does a button in a html table cell enlarges the cell?

Tags: html, forms, button, html-table

I am new in html... I try to put some buttons into the cells of a table with the following code (note: no CSS, no JS, just pure html):

```
<table border="1">
    <td>
        <form action="/test/"> <input type="submit" value="Log off"></form>
    </td>
</table>
```

This code puts the button into the cell indeed, but it somehow enlarges the cell. In other words, the cell looks higher than necessary for the button.

[image]

How can I get rid of this behavior?

Comment: Which browser leaves such a gap below the button? Only IE 7 and older, I think, and maybe some browsers that you might find in a museum of technology.

Comment: I see this on google chrome :(

Comment: Oh, the problem appears on Chrome, too, but only in Quirks Mode. If you start your document with `<!doctype html>`, the problem disappears on Chrome. See https://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/quirks-mode.html

Comment: Thanks mate, you have nailed it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use inline styles or CSS stylesheets. Is there any reason why you are against using CSS? Really you should create a stylesheet to properly format your HTML elements.

## Using inline-style

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <form style='margin: 0; padding: 0;' action="/test/">
                <input type="submit" value="Log off" />
            </form>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/3QABM/

## Move the form outside of the table

This will only work if you have one form in your table

```
<form action="/test/">
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="submit" value="Log off" />
            </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
</form>
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/hs4C9/

I know you stated you do not want to use css, but you could use a reset css stylesheet, for example:
http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Comment: Thank you. The inline versions worked, the html4 version didnt (cell and button remained the same as before)? What could be the reason behind this? To answer your question: I have lots of programming experience, but pretty much nothing in web development, so for now I would like to keep it simple and do the baby steps first:)

Comment: Sorry Vadganaj, my HTML4 version was not valid as per the W3c standards. Therefore the only way to do this is in stylesheets, or inline styles.

Answer (score 2):

The spacing between the button and the cell borders can be removed by using the attribute `cellpadding=0` in the `<table>` tag. But it affects all cells.

The spacing below the button only appears in some old browsers, and there is no valid way to remove it in HTML (i.e. without CSS) in the general case. However, if the logic of the page allows it (there are no other forms in the table), you can nest the table inside the form:

```
<form action="/test/">
<table border="1" cellpadding="0">
<td>
 <input type="submit" value="Log off">
</td>
</table>
</form>
```

**Additional trick** (ugly hack):

If you really want to do this with a table containing several forms, so that the above method cannot be used, you can use invalid HTML markup where the forms have table cells as children:

```
<table border="1" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
  <form action="/test/"><td><input type="submit" value="Log off"></td></form>
  <form action="/test/"><td><input type="submit" value="Log off"></td></form>
</table>
```

It’s invalid by any HTML spec, but browsers don’t care. The point is that in some old browsers, a `form` element has a default bottom margin (about one empty line or so), and this trick fools those browsers into omitting the margin (or at least it’s not inside the cell, since the cell ends before the form).

As mentioned in other answers, using CSS would really be better. It would need nothing more complicated than this element into the `head` part (actually it works elsewhere, too, but `head` is the valid place):

```
<style>
form { margin: 0 }
</style>
```

Comment: I would like to add multiple buttons next to each other. <table border="1" cellpadding="0">
<td>
 <form action="/test/"><input type="submit" value="Log off"></form>  
</td>
</table>     this gives me the same problem :(

Comment: Sorry mate, this is exactly what I am planning to do. Pls read the original question and note that I wrote my first tag in html only couple days ago.

Comment: Yes, I've read.. but you should consider another source of learning. Here is a nice one: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/learn/html, http://webdesign.about.com/od/layout/a/aa111102a.htm,

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: COMMENT 
This is maybe harsh to say, but if you're doing pure HTML, what are you using a log-off button for? And why not use some simple css? Because with css, as mark already said, the solution is fairly easy. Css is mostly much more difficult than in this case.
Nowadays css is mostly part of html. Unless you want to make an oldschool styled site, you can't go without it anymore. That's simply how they build it around, and that's why a lot of features from HTML(4) are deprecated in HTML5. -> they have moved to css.
Just saying. ;-)

css approach, should work

```
input[type=submit] {
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    display: inline;
    //and any other style rules you wish to add or modify
}
```

hope this helps

Comment: Not an answer to the question. Valid *comment*, though.

Comment: yeah but i don't have 50 reputation which was needed to use the comment function on the original post.. ;s

Comment: Because I lied... its not just html. I am working on a proof of concept type of a page with various web services which I try to experiment with. In couple days I made a pretty good progress considering that I never did web development before. But this button thing just make my ugly page even more ugly. My point is once I have the functionalities in place I can tidy up the page and give it a nice look. But can you show me what would be the CSS solution for this problem? Or should I post another question for this?

Comment: I'll edit my post asap with the css solution; it's not that hard though; basically all you need to do is reset all margins, paddings and use display:inline. I'll re-edit.